# iPhone SDK - how to hide and show the status bar together with the MPMoviePlayerController controls?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller, statusbar

I'm using a `MPMoviePlayerViewController` to show a movie. I have set the `MPMoviePlayerController` to fullscreen. Now I want to hide the status bar as soon as the fullscreen controls start to fade out and show the status bar if the controls are visible.

If I'm using a `UIWebView` all this happens automatically. The status bar fades in and out together with the controls. How would you do that with a `MPMoviePlayerController`?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3):

You can use to hide status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

and to show status bar

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

The animated bit is now deprecated so just use:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: It's not the animated bit that is deprecated, but that form has been replaced with another that requires the style of animation to specified: `setStatusBarHidden:(BOOL)hidden withAnimation:(UIStatusBarAnimation)animation`

Answer (score 0):

This will happen automagically for you once you use the `MPMoviePlayerController` property `controlStyle` and set to `MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen`.

```
player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen;
```